# Dynamics 2011 Developer Resources Service Endpoint Shows Machine Name

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

On my on-premise Dynamics 2011 instance, when I go into Customizations -> Developer Resources, I see the following under Service Endpoints:

> **Discovery Service**
>
> Protocol: SOAP
>
> `http://machine_name/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc`

However, I've set up a DNS entry `dynamics.company.com` for the server. And on the dynamics server, I've set the host name for http port 80 bindings to `dynamics.company.com`. I'd like to see the service endpoint showing `dynamics.company.com` rather than the machine name.

***What else do I need to do to fix the service endpoints shown in Developer Resources?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Server name in the database by performing this query:

```
Update [MSCRM_CONFIG].[dbo].[DeploymentProperties]
Set NVarCharColumn = 'dynamics.company.com:80'
WHERE
ColumnName in (
'ADDeploymentSdkRootDomain',
'ADDiscoveryRootDomain',
'ADSdkRootDomain',
'ADWebApplicationRootDomain')
```

I used this in a test environment where the URLs listed on the Developer Resources didn't include the Domain name, and needed to.

Comment: By the way I think this can also be done via the CRM Deployment Manager on the server. The properties window has a tab called "Web Address" which appears to read from the DeploymentProperties table. So a SQL query is not strictly required.

Comment: @ZaidMasud Nice to know.  I knew there must have been some supported method, but I'm not a deployment admin (although I do have rights to the database) so I was stuck with SQL method.